# Broken workbook, VBE shows every worksheet twice with weird symbol

Tags: excel, vba

When I open a specific workbook, I receive a few VBA errors ("Automation error", "Compile error: Method or data member not found").
I opened the Visual Basic Editor and found that in the document tree under "Microsoft Excel Objects" every single worksheet suddenly appears twice: Once with the regular icon for a worksheet and a second time with a weird blue icon that I've never seen before: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHnbl.png)
The entries with the weird icon show the "CodeName" I had specified for the worksheets but do not show any worksheet name, wile the entries with the regular icons show the "CodeName" followed by a "1" and the correct worksheet name.

This has now already happened the second time to me, both times with the same workbook. The first time (maybe two months ago), I've just deleted the file and continued with a backup from the day before. I will probably do the same this time, but would like to understand the issue.

What did I do?
The file was alright when I opened it the last time. I have then added some data, modified a UserForm and added some VBA code (nothing special). The workbook had initially been created on a computer with German Excel, the latest change took place on an English system (but this process works fine with other workbooks).
I found this link where another user described the same issue 6 years ago: https://superuser.com/questions/1005482/excel-creates-non-existent-worksheets-in-vba-project-explorer
However, the suggested solutions do not work for me. Nothing changes when I save the file as *.xlsb. When I save it as *.xlsx, the entires with the blue icons disappear but the entries with the regular icons remain with the invalid "CodeName", breaking some of my macros.

Did anyone experience the same issue before? Any ideas what might went wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It would seam your workbook is corrupt.   You best (only?) option is to create a new workbook, and copy your data into it.  Save a copy often, so if a step copies the corruption you can roll back

Comment: If you have issues with corrupted files, I recommend the follwing: Copy everything into a brand new workbook. If you want to be 100 % secure copy data only (without formatting) because this can copy some issues too. Copy over your macros. Make sure to save the file as `xlsb` as it is very unlikely that this gets corrupted. I had already more than 50 issues with `xlsm/xlsx` files but since I stick to `xlsb` no corrupted file ever occured to me.

Comment: Thanks for your answers so far. As written before, I've been lucky enough to have a recent backup, so there's no need to restore. Otherwise the suggested process of copying into a new workbook would have been really annoying, because the different sheets contain a lot of formulas that are linked to each other. Not to mention formatting and charts...

Comment: @MrToiz Always good to have a backup, saves a lot of time and nerves! If you can save as `xlsb` this would prevent future issues of that kind. I've never personally had a corrupt `xlsb` nor have I heard about one, people are just always complaining about corrupt `xlsm/xlsx` files.